# Displaying an image on ScrewTurn wiki

Tags: image, wiki, screwturn

I'm sure I'm making a simple mistake but I'm having a lot of difficulty displaying an image in my ScrewTurn wiki.

The markup I am using:

```
[imageleft|Extreme Programming|goodlooking.jpg]
```

What I'm seeing displayed is a broken image with the caption.
An attachment named goodlooking.jpg is uploaded to this page.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you uploaded the image as a Page Attachment (at the bottom of the page), then you need to include the page reference in the markup.  For example, if the page was named "Test-Page", it would look something like this:

```
[imageauto|Extreme Programming|{UP(Test-Page)}goodlooking.jpg]
```

If the page is not in the default namespace (i.e. "root"), then you need to include the namespace reference as well:

```
[imageauto|Extreme Programming|{UP(NamespaceHere.Test-Page)}goodlooking.jpg]
```

If you use the "Image" icon in the editor (near the center of the icons), it will handle the markup for you.  Just make sure you click the "Browse Page Attachments" checkbox to see page attachments.  Also, you may need to Save the page at least once before you can upload and attach Page Attachments.