# Screwturn Wiki Album using Uploaded Images

Tags: screwturn

I support a website for WWII veterans. In my efforts to support them, I just added the Screwturn Wiki (3.0) to the website. This will allow me to do many things, but among them, to build albums for the group. More importantly, it will allow others to contribute to those albums.

To that end, I made some code snippets that would allow the user to insert into the album any image uploaded to that page. To fetch that image into the snippet, I followed the example on this page: [Displaying an image on ScrewTurn wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840530/displaying-an-image-on-screwturn-wiki)

The problem is, using the {UP(AlbumPage)}FileName.jpg example appears to be slow. It calls this page: /Wiki/GetFile.aspx?Page=AlbumPage&File=FileName.jpg and that, multiplied many times, makes the album page incredibly slow.

So, is there another way to fetch uploaded images associated with a given page? One that is hopefully much more quick than this method? I'd like to have a nice efficient page that loads in under 30 seconds and doesn't take forever when moving from image to image.

Any and all clues appreciated.

Comment: Are the original photograph files being used for display on the page (ie. high resolution photos)?  I would assume some are if others are allowed to upload.  If so, have you considered scaling them down resolution wise to limit the amount of bandwidth used?

Comment: That's a good point, and, yes, they are full res. I'd like to keep them that way if I can, but this might be my last-resort solution. Is there a way to tell Screwturn to store them at a specific size on upload? That would solve the users-not-listening problem. :)

Comment: Not that I know of.  You might be better off using Flickr etc for the photos part specifically.

Comment: While the vast majority of my (potential) users are not WWII vets -- more often than not, they are the children of those vets -- they're still somewhat computer illiterate. So, the simpler I keep this, the better off it will be. :) I did just discover that I can re-size the photos once they're uploaded and I have access to the STW code base, so it's possible to modify things on the receiving end... I was hoping for an easier way to manage this though. Thanks for the feedback. :)